# How to Enable Cloudwatch JVM Monitoring

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

I am currently running docker swarm cluster spread amongst three ec2 instances. I am trying to enable jvm monitoring and following the instructions here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/generating-sdk-metrics.html
I have updated the Dockerfile entrypoint to run java with -Dcom.amazonaws.sdk.enableDefaultMetrics option. However, I don't see any metrics or the AWSSDK/Java namespace in cloudwatch. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you got the region configured correctly? The metrics may be getting published to a different region to what you are looking at. See the link you posted for how to configure the region.